# Ruby: creating a class object using the name of the class?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Please don't judge me too harshly because I am so new to this topic that I don't know how to ask the question (or what to search to get answers):

I am learning nested forms in Sinatra, but encountered something I don't understand which relates to Ruby.

See the code snippet below--while trying to test the code in `rake console`, I typed in `Team`, and was surprised to see an object created with the name "Team". But if I type in `my_team = Team.new(params)`, I get an error message that `undefined local variable or method 'params' for main:Object`

If I typed in anything else, say 'man', I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'man' for main:Object`

Why does the name of the class result in an instance of the class? Shouldn't it require `Class_name.new` to create an object?

```
class Team

  attr_accessor :name
    TEAM = []

    def initialize(params)
      @name = params[:team][:name]
      TEAM << self
    end

    def self.all
      TEAM
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, everything is an object, thus classes are objects (and they are instances of the class [Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html).

`Team` is an instance of the class Class (shortened as "a class") whereas `Team.new` builds an instance of `Team`. Instances of Class have a certain behavior, which allows to create instances of themselves via the method `#new`.

Now, any arguments passed to a method in ruby must be defined in your current [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html) meaning that if `params` is undefined, you are not allowed to do `Team.new(params)` right off the bat. Defining a local variable (that will go into the binding) before accessing it is easy :

```
params = { team: { name: 'StackOverflow' } }
Team.new(params)
```

will work.

Comment: The distinction btw "an instance of the class Class" and "an instance of a class" explains what was happening. That's why after I typed `Team`, I could do `Team.name` and get `"Team"`, but nothing else (such as `Team.all`) worked. Also thanks for the eg for using 'params'.

Answer (score 1):

I loaded that code snippet into irb and `Team` does not return an instance of the class `Team`.

The parameter you pass in (`params`) when you instantiate `Team` has to BE something; if `params` is not currently a local variable assigned to an object, ruby will refuse to instantiate `Team`.

When you're working with a framework like Rails or Sinatra, `params` is a hash that the Client (your browser) sends to your app inside a HTTP request. In this case, when the params hash hits your app, it would look something like:

`{:team => {:name => "Team 1's name"}}`

What is probably happening in your app is that user clicks a button like "Create Team" in the browser, and the data entered into that form, such as 'Team Name', is put into the `params` hash.

If you just took the pure Ruby code that you've provided and just did `Team.new(params)`, that would be the equivalent of `Team.new(nil)` if `params` wasn't assigned to anything.

By the way, that's a pretty cool piece of Ruby - it allows you to do `Team.all` to return an array of previously created Teams.

`.all` is a Class Method. If you want to understand more about Class Methods, I have a [little blog post on it](http://yorkshireman.github.io/eigenclass).

Hope all that helps? Feel free to ask more questions if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post--a lot of useful conceptual examples. I am going to look through the rest of my code and see if `Team.new(nil)` is the problem with my Views files.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to always post a link to your github repo so people can properly have a poke around the code and get it working for you. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: I do have a link, but the code is 'primitive' (& messed up), so I didn't think it'd be worth anybody's time to sift through: https://github.com/CodeByLine/sinatra-nested-forms-lab-superheros-v-000